# Mongoose - Query latest document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query for the latest document in my database. I wrote following function for it but it doesn't return the latest entry, instead it just returns the first one in the db. I tried find() instead of findOne() but it returned an object inside an array which isn't what I want. Is there a native mongoose function that returns the latest document in form of an object?

```
const getLatestRound = module.exports.getLatestRound = function(callback){
    SmallHistory.findOne().limit(1).sort({ date: -1 }).exec((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            callback(new Error('Error querying SmallHistory (getLatestRound())'));
            return;
        }
        if(data) {
            callback(null, data);
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Replace by places `limit` and `sort`: `SmallHistory.findOne().sort({ date: -1 }).limit(1).exec((err, data) => {`. And you don't need `limit` when you use `findOne`.

Comment: why use limit for findOne ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sort()` and `limit()` are in the wrong order; you're limiting BEFORE your sort backward.   Change it to:

```
SmallHistory.findOne().sort({ date: -1 }).limit(1).exec((err, data)
```