# Nodejs: Mongoose find latest entry of the DB with filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I've been trying to find the right answer to my problem and even if some questions [come pretty close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533178/mongoose-query-latest-document), I'm not sure any of them apply to my particular situation:

I have a MongoDB that is constantly being fed by info and I would like to query the latest document but specifying a filter:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    model.findOne({ bar: "foo" }, {}, { sort: { n: -1 } }, function(
      err,
      obj
    ) {
      resolve(obj);
    });
  });
```

The code above doesn't achieve what I'm trying to do properly... My guess is that it looks first for a document with the key bar / value foo and then sorts the results however, since the "results" are really just a single result, it sorts 'nothing' per se and therefore returns the first 'foo' document that was found in the DB.

The DB has many 'foo' documents and I want to query the latest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is n here ?

Comment: It's a timestamp

Comment: I have pasted a solution  can you please try and respond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you intend to get the latest document containing foo at bar key ,so this will return the latest document.

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        model.findOne({ bar: "foo" }, {}, { sort: { '_id': -1 } }, function(
          err,
          obj
        ) {
          resolve(obj);
        });
      });
```

Comment: Hey there Sagar! Indeed it worked. Thanks!